# CSS Opacity for a button

Tags: html, css, web, opacity

I have a button in HTML and I have to add opacity to it. I want to use CSS to do that. Here is my existing CSS code for button:

```
.btn_nav{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:68px;
background-color:#323232;
border-bottom:2px solid #777777;
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question, or did you just need us to link this for you?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: I see you've put a lot of research effort into this...

Comment: I  suspect that, in fact, you don't want opacity, you want a transparent background color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few different ways to apply opacity to a button. Here is one of them.

```
.btn_nav{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:68px;
    background-color:#323232;
    border-bottom:2px solid #777777;
    /*Below are two new line which enable opacity*/
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this css property

```
    opacity:0.2;  // change values as you like
```